# How to use Microsoft.Cdn profiles/secrets to enable certificate?

Tags: azure, cdn, azure-rm-template

I am trying Azure cdn certificate using ARM template or bicep but im getting an error.
here is the piece of code:

```
{
    "type": "Microsoft.Cdn/profiles/secrets",
    "apiVersion": "2020-09-01",
     "name": "string",
      "properties": {
     "parameters": {
      "type": "CustomerCertificate",
       "certificateAuthority": "string",
       "secretSource": {
       "id": ""
},
"secretVersion": "string",
"subjectAlternativeNames": [ "string" ],
"useLatestVersion": "bool"
  }
}
}
```

Comment: Can you please share the error you are getting ?

Comment: Getting this error: {"status":"Failed","error":{"code":"DeploymentFailed","message":"At least one resource deployment operation failed. Please list deployment operations for details. Please see https://aka.ms/DeployOperations for usage details.","details":[
{"code":"BadRequest","message":"{\r\n  \"error\": {\r\n    \"code\": \"BadRequest\",\r\n    \"message\": \"No secret name found in provided SecretSource id.\"\r\n  }\r\n}"}]}}

Comment: Please use the whole resource I'd like I have provided on the below code : /subscriptions/<SubscriptionID>/resourceGroups/<resourceGroupName>/providers/Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/<KeyvaultName>/certificates/<CertificateName>

Comment: If the answer was helpful, Please [Accept it as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work), so that others who encounter the same issue can find this solution and fix their problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you have ***existing CDN*** , then you can use the below to set certificate in CDN :

**Bicep Code:**

```
resource profile 'Microsoft.Cdn/profiles@2020-09-01' existing = {
  name:'CDN Name'
}

resource symbolicname 'Microsoft.Cdn/profiles/secrets@2020-09-01' = {
  name: 'CustomerCert'
  parent: profile
  properties: {
    parameters: {
      type: 'CustomerCertificate'
      certificateAuthority: 'CA name of Certificate' // issuing authority of the certificate
      secretSource: {
        id: '/subscriptions/<SubscriptionID>/resourceGroups/<resourceGroupName>/providers/Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/<KeyvaultName>/certificates/<CertificateName>' //keyvaultresourceID where the certificate is stored
      }
      secretVersion: '' 
      subjectAlternativeNames: [ 
        'DNS Names'
      ]
      useLatestVersion: true // if true then keep the secret version blank
    }
  }
}
```

**Note:** Please make sure that before running the above you will have to ***[`Grant Azure CDN access to your key vault`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cdn/cdn-custom-ssl?tabs=option-2-enable-https-with-your-own-certificate#grant-azure-cdn-access-to-your-key-vault)***.

Comment: I already done it that. What would be the input of CA name of Certificate?

Comment: @Abkade , It should be the issuer for your certificate . you can refer this for more information [document](https://cheapsslsecurity.com/blog/what-is-a-certificate-authority-ca/)